# Transferred to my own contract address

Tags: erc-20

I created a custom token ie GGT
Works fine BUT I transferred 1000 of them from my main account to what i though was a wallet address but it turned out to be the GGT contract address (mine)[enter link description here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x939bcae5a45558ea20da7f42377017fef3ff748f30edb5aadda3bc7a9875a710)
How do I get this balance back as I am showing 1000 less than i should 
OR can I not get them back!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the tokens back